# Gallery based on grid - overflow of content and images ratio issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am exercising my web development skills by building a simple gallery app. Unfortunately CSS turned out to be biggest problem.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.searchbox {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.gallery {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);
  gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  flex: 9;
  min-height: 0;
}

.title {
  flex: 1;
}

.pagination {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="searchbox">SEARCHBOX</div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
      <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/100"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
      <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination">PAGINATION</div>
</div>
```

My gallery will have 20 images per page (4x5). The images might be of different sizes - some might be horizontal, some vertical, some square.

The problems that I have:

1. The images are scaled in a way that does not keep their original ratio
2. The "app" does not take only 100% of the height - it takes more, and I need to scroll. Ideally, 100% should be taken always
3. The "pagination" DIV landed somewhere inside of the grid. It should be placed below the grid.

I have to admit that I tried many different ways to fix it, however I was either getting into even weirder results, or not fixing the problem at all.

What is wrong with my CSS?

Comment: In the end, I threw `grid` out, and used `flex`. I don't get why `grid` overflows its container as it does. `flex` behaves more responsive actually, so I find it better for my need (I can have as many images in the rows as my horizontal size allows)

Answer (score 2):

First take the height and width out of your html, body - it's directly affecting your image sizes

```
html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Then drop the margin from your main container, it's causing an overflow. Maybe you meant to use padding?

```
.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0 10%;*/ <--- Remove
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

After that you can use the object-fit property to align your image positions :) It's important that your height and width are set though!

```
img {
  display: block;
  flex: 9;
  min-height: 0;
  width:300px;
  max-height:300px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

I hope this helps! https://jsfiddle.net/1txLvoh6/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I see some issue in your version: the app still requires scrolling. Ideally, all images should be scaled so that the whole page fits in the view; the Pagination DIV is still inside of the grid.

Comment: Oh I see, well then go ahead and add `height:100%` back into the html, body css and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer this variant:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-rows: 1em max-content 1em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.searchbox {
    /* your styles for searchbox */
}

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    /* columns can be equal too, using calc and without justification on center */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    /* 4 gaps between rows + 2 gaps above and below of gallery + search and pager heights */
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, calc(20vh - 2em));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    flex: 9;
    min-height: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.title {
    flex: 1;
}

.pagination {
    /* your styles for pagination */
}
```